# Enabling ReadyBoost on an arbitrary drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, readyboost

Is there any hack to enable ReadyBoost on an storage device at will? It seems to be only available on USB, flash based devices, but at work we have plenty of motherboards with an small ide-like connector and little (512M - 1024M) SSDs connected to it.

The option to enable ReadyBoost on that drive right clicking on it, is, of course, non existant. That's what I'm asking, how to get to it.

Maybe a registry hack? Obscure CLI magic?

The SSD pass the winsat tests with honours, is in no way as fast as a modern SSD, but way faster than common USB flash drives.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. I have a 50GB SSD on d: that I'd like to use (it's only being used for pagefile on a 16GB RAM system) but the Readyboost tab is simply not there despite the service already started and running. When I first installed the drive the option was there, but after a subsequent config change to use AHCI instead of IDE, the Readyboost tab is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

[Winmatrix - Enable ready boost on slow USB drives?](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/13095-enable-readyboost-on-slow-usb-drive/)

Comment: No, as I say at the second paragraph.