# Using ready boost on a partition than USB drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, speed

Is it possible to use ready boost on a partition of my HDD(I have only one) instead of a USB drive. I want to so this because sata write speed is faster than USB. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable ReadyBoost on a second internal HDD?](http://superuser.com/questions/30025/enable-readyboost-on-a-second), [How can I use my SSD as a ReadyBoost cache disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/93538), [Enabling ReadyBoost on an arbitrary drive](http://superuser.com/questions/426757), [Make ReadyBoost use SATA instead of USB drive](http://superuser.com/questions/463140), [I recently attached an external HD with eSATA in Windows 7. When I try to enable ReadyBoost, I click Test in the device Properties and nothing happens. Why?](http://superuser.com/questions/116330) ...

Comment: What matters is random read speed where flash wins. Not that ReadyBoost has ever been known to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a "ReadyBoost" on your hard drive, swap space.

Your computer will sometimes use swap space/page file instead of RAM. I'm not an expert but there is no need to set up "ReadyBoost" on a hard drive.